# passing the text to another class

Tags: java

Sir/Madam,

Currently im having 3 classes, main, jframe and newclass. i have created a jframe in jframe class with some text fields and buttons, what i want to do is when i click on the button the text inside textfields should be able to access from the newclass without writting the code inside the jframe class. i tried to create a object of newclass in jframe class and call it when the button clicked. but that doesnt help.

Comment: Write public getter  method for your class properties to access in any class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make some getter method in `jframe` class, example:

```
public String getName(){
    return JT_fname.getText();
}
// same for age, id...
```

Then, you can access these data by calling these method. Example:

```
public static main (String arg[]) {
    jframe jf = new .....
    //jf.open or show ......... bla bla bla
    System.out.println(jf.getName());

}
```

P/S try to apply code convention on naming Class name, method.... It's more easy to read.

Comment: You are welcome! Could you please make my answer "Accepted" or upvote it. Thanks

Comment: sir one more thing please, what should i include in the btn_insert.addActionListener(new  ActionListener() {}, when the button click it should display the text.

Comment: @AlexDRex, what do you mean for the "display the text"? If you want to show a message Dialog, you can read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html